# Python programming pattern for a variety of engines (backends)

Tags: python, design-patterns, multiple-instances

What would be the best way to implement the following behaviour: I have an interface represented by a function `ans = my_interface(args)`, I have several implementations of this function and I want to give the user permission to select one of the implementations by setting a parameter.

The obvious solution would be to make each implementation a function with identical interfaces and in `my_interface` process the parameter and depending on its value call one of them. If I want to extend, I need to add a new function with a new implementation of the engine and change `my_interface` to process a new engine's name. And I have to be aware of the proper interface here. I don't think it is the smartest way.

I would also apreciate a link on the book or discussion of this matter. I have found a similar functionality in Keras for example, where it can use either Tensorflow or PyTorch backends. Does anyone know how it is implemented?

Comment: Sounds like you want an abstract class rather than just a top level function. Other than that, you seem to be looking for a Facade, Factory, or perhaps Strategy pattern

Comment: Is there a source available where I can learn those? I have tried several books on this subject but they are too vague and esoteric for me. I want to follow a real-world example.

Comment: The [`design-patterns` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/design-patterns/info) has a literature list. A common critique is that the concept makes more sense in lower-level languages like C++ but it's good to know at least in a general sense what they mean even if you use Python.

Comment: Having said that, it seems that your question could be reduced to just "how can I implement classes with an identical API" which is the question you are asked when you start reading an introduction to polymorphism in OOP. (Functions with an identical signature would be even simpler, of course, but often too simple.)

Comment: Patterns themselves are vague, but this seems almost exactly what you're asking for https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/python/example

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use classes and design patterns, you can try something like that:

```py
def _my_interface_engine_A():
    print("engine A")
    return 0

def _my_interface_engine_B():
    print("engine B")
    return 1

def _my_interface_engine_C():
    print("engine C")
    return 2

def my_interface(*args, **kwargs):
    engine = kwargs.pop("engine", "A")  # A is the default engine
    return globals()[f"_my_interface_engine_{engine}"](*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
>>> print(my_interface())
engine A
0

>>> print(my_interface(engine="B"))
engine B
1
```

If you add another interface, you just need to name your function `_my_interface_engine_X` and let `my_interface` function untouched.
`my_interface` acts as a proxy to your other interfaces.